# How to delete slides from PowerPoint using c#?

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint

I want to delete a particular slide from a PowerPoint presentation using C#. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: I would suggest checking out the FileHelpers libraries, but I'm not sure they help with PowerPoint.

Answer (score 6):

Open PowerPoint stack and per normal COM and use

```
var powerPoint = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
var presentation = powerPoint.Presentations.Open(fileName);

presentation.Slides[x].Delete();
presentation.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Aspose for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.total-for-.net/default.aspx). It provides a ton of libraries for interfacing with Office file formats.